# Is debouncing necessary for a power switch?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, switches, debounce

A few months ago I asked for help designing a circuit for powering on a microcontroller using a tact switch, and  I finally just prototyped the circuit that @Jonathan-S. suggested. It works great. However, I neglected to consider any effects of contact bounce in the tact switch. I'm not seeing any ill effects, but I'm wondering if bouncing could cause glitching and I wonder if some sort of hardware debounce is necessary? If so, could someone suggest a simple circuit?  My current schematic is below. "Boost EN" connects to a microcontroller output that is driven high out powerup to keep the boost converter operating, and "SW3" connect to an input on the uC.

[image]

Comment: The parts in your circuit may impose requirements on this. In general though, chips care moreso about the reset signal having the proper shape and rise time. You can usually find drawn examples of these requirements in microcontroller datasheets.

Comment: does something else make the power stay on once it turns on?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, the uC drives the "Boost EN" line high at startup to keep the power on.

Comment: then, does the bouncing matter?

Comment: I'm not sure-- I do have other ICs, like an IMU and EEPROM. I wasn't sure if it would good for them for Vcc to rise/fall repeatedly during the time that it takes the MCU to power up and drive the Boost EN line high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is maybe.
Longer answer, well it depends on everything else is your circuit. What frequency does the switch bounce at and how fast does everything else turn on/off, charge and discharge? What happens to the system if it gets rapidly power cycled a number of times? (assuming the bounce propogates through the power train fully)

How to deal with this varies, but a simple option is to pop a 200nF capacitor in parrallel with R5. When the switch is closed it will still rise quickly, but it will take 10ms for the capacitor to discharge when the switch is open. This 10ms is more than likely long enough for any bouncing to stop. This sort of simple capacitor debouncing is pretty common for switches, becuase they're human actuated there's rarely the need for them to be very fast, after all no real input to the switch is going to be 100Hz is it?
You can tweak the capacitor to change the time if you need something else from it.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping a simple cap would give me some peace of mind, but I wasn't sure. I'll experiment with this.

Comment: Quick question: How did you calculate the discharge time for the capacitor at 10 mS? If it's in parallel with the resistor the series resistance is very low, correct? Thanks!

Comment: It'll still discharge through that resistor, so it's still 5RC to discharge.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding-- if it's parallel with R5 why does it discharge through R5?

Comment: When the switch is open, it's just the capacitor connected to the resistor. At this point, the capacitor is holding a charge, and R5 is the path for that charge to GND.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood the placement. I thought you meant across the resistor, [like this](https://www.mowrystrings.com/C18a.jpg). Did you mean [like this](https://www.mowrystrings.com/C18b.jpg)?

Comment: I meant the first image. Look at this simulation https://tinyurl.com/2gdn33ow

Comment: Great, thanks for all your help! I'm obviously a novice, but I was just reading up on RC networks and I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

That's what power supervisors, load switches, and tracking regulators are for, if required. It matters a lot more if you have complex digital ICs, ICs with multiple power rails, or many digital ICs, and a combinatio of all of the above.